# How can I use math function in laravel eloquent query?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I want to do sum  math calculation in my eloquent query .I have a variable which must be multiple to some of my DB filed and if more than 3000 then the parent item must be in my result.

**1)Jewel model:**

```
class Jewel extends Model
{
use HasFactory;

public function jewelsItems(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\JewelsItem');
}

 }
```

**2)JewelsItem Model:**

```
class JewelsItem extends Model
{

//has weight,fee field

use HasFactory;


protected $table = 'jewel_items';

public function jewel(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Jewel');
}

}
```

the query must get me all jewel that have at least a jewelsItem with `(weight*($varibale+fee)) > 5000`.

**note1:** $varibale is not a DB field.

**note2:** I don't want to use Raw Expressions cause of theirs vulnerabilities.

Comment: Pretty sure you'll have to use `DB::raw` for this, not sure what vulnerabilities you mean since laravel escapes everything for you.

Comment: Ok so how can I prevent from SQL injection in this way?@thursday_dan

Comment: That's what I'm saying laravel will do it automatically, you don't need to take any additional steps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to try this:

```php
return Jewel::whereHas('jewelsItems', function ($query) use ($variable) {
    $query->whereRaw("(weight*({$varibale}+fee)) > 5000");
})->get();
```